# Set ISO country code on non-root phone with adb

Tags: adb, permissions, shizuku

I want to try the new body-temperature mode of my pixel 8 pro's IR sensor, however that is locked to the US. Apparently the app checks for the SIM ISO country code so I would like to change that to US. Someone wrote a guide that uses the apps Shizuku and Carrier Vanity Name to change the code. I would like to do the same using `adb`. However, executing `setprop gsm.sim.operator.iso-country us` results in `Failed to set property 'gsm.sim.operator.iso-country' to 'us'. See dmesg for error reason.`

I suppose it's a permission problem, but without root access, I can't access `dmesg` to look for the reason of the error. How can I debug this? And how can Shizuku execute the command that I can't, when from my understanding I need to grant Shizuku permissions using adb in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

Such features are locked by all the carriers in your country.  They are also locked properly by the Phone manufacturers because they cant risk being fined for breaching the local laws.

They don't just use the SIM, but also the Carrier, information from GPS, information from Cell Towers and information from Wifi connections.

Your chance of bypassing it are slim to zero.  If someone has managed to do it, then ask that someone.

Your best bet is to do what I did (to get around a different restriction).  Look for a Chinese phone on Ebay or Aliexpress that advertises this feature, and buy it.  Note, it can't be a normal well known brand.  It needs to be unregulated and unknown brand.  The instructions will probably in Chinese, I had to get them translated by a friend.  Also beware of false claims.

Comment: There are enough reports that have successfully unlocked the body temp mode by changing the ISO country code using the aforementioned Shizuku + Carrier Vanity Name apps, I just want to know if there is another way to unlock or why only this way works. Buying another phone is not going to help.